# generate multiple pdf file and zip it

Tags: php, codeigniter, zip, mpdf

I have a situation like create multiple pdf files and download as zip file.

I have tried with below code

```
    function downloadZip()
    {
      if ($this->input->post('btn_submit')) 
      {

        $data = array(
             'results' => $this->Mdi_download_invoices->download_pdf_files($this->input->post('client_id'))
        );

        foreach ($data['results'] as $d)
        {
             $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
             $html = $this->load->view('download_all_invoices/pdf',$d,true);
             $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
             $mpdf->Output(); //this will create a pdf file in next tab

             $this->load->library('zip');
             $this->zip->add_data();
             $this->zip->archive('/var/www/my_backup.zip');
             $this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');
        }
    }
```

How can I store all pdf file in the array??

Comment: You can save the PDF to a file by providing the `Output` method with a location to put it. Then add the file to the zip?

Comment: @JonStirling thanks for your answer, But how can I save multiple pdf files through the loop??

Comment: You're already doing that, you're just not saving them, just make sure you give each file a unique name.

Comment: @JonStirling I tried what u said but it creates the only single file  $mpdf->Output($d->invoice_id, \Mpdf\Output\Destination::DOWNLOAD);

Comment: Why did you add `\Mpdf\Output\Destination::DOWNLOAD`!? You need it on your local file system to add it to the zip. You should also move some of the zip functionality out of the loop, download should be after the loop, the rest should be before, then `add_data with the file path of the pdf you generated.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($data['results'] as $d)
        {
             $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
             $html = $this->load->view('download_all_invoices/pdf',$d,true);
             $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
             $mpdf->Output(); //this will create a pdf file in next tab

             $this->zip->add_data('file-'.$i.'.pdf',$d); 
             $i++;
        }

             $this->zip->archive('/var/www/my_backup.zip');
             $this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');
```

By this you can add each PDF file in Zip and after you the loop you can generate a zip file and download it. I have not tested it so please ignore syntax error but you will get an idea from it.